# Print line between to strings, if another string is found

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

I have a text document with blocks of code, separated by $.
Now, if a certain string is found between the $'s I want to print every line out between the $'s. The string I search for is not always on the same place.
And I want to loop through the whole document, until I've printed all blocks out.
I already tried different approaches, but no success.

The document looks like this:

```
$    
aa   
string    
$
aa   
bb  
cc  
$
aa  
bb
string  
cc  
$
```

Output should be:

```
$    
aa   
string    
$
aa  
bb
string  
cc  
$
```

Last attempt code:

```
def usefullInfo():
    data_list = []
    with open ("file.txt") as f:
        data = f.read()
        marker, pos = "string", 0
        while data.find(marker) != -1:
            pos = data.find(marker)
            start = data.find ("$", pos)
            stop = data.find ("$", pos)
            data_list.append(data[start:stop])
            data = data[stop+1:]
    print (data_list)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Included last attempt...

Answer (score 0):

Toggle write variable each time you encounter a "$"

```
def usefullInfo():
    write = False
    with open ("file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            if '$' in line:
                write = not write
            if write:
                print (line)
        print("$")

usefullInfo()
```

is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as F:
    lines = F.readlines()

search_string = 'string'
long_line     = ''.join([x.replace(' ','') for x in lines])
blocks        = [x.lstrip() for x in long_line.split('$')]

for block in blocks:
    if not(block=='' or block=='\n') and search_string in block.split('\n'):
        print('$\n'+block+'$')
```

output:

```
$
aa
string
$
$
aa
bb
string
cc
$
```

Comment: This works indeed for this simplified example.
The file with the data I look for, and thus the string as well consists of multiple words, and sometimes with one white space as first character on the line. I figured out it has something to do with the "long_line" in your code. However I'm just a beginner in python, so if you could suggest your ideas on this, it would be very welcome!

Comment: Something like: search_string = re.match("/port config\b/g", lines), where the string is "port config"+ some variables such as "test interface 0/0" but this returns following error:     
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I would suggest you make your example a bit closer to the real case then. Because otherwise it is hard to imagine every possible case of how this string could look like -> increased complexity of the code. if it is just about the white spaces, just try removing the ".replace(' ','')" in the long_string line.

Answer (score 0):

Store the input strings in a queue.
Set `write = True` if the search string is found.
Whenever `$` is encountered in the input remove all the items from the queue and also print those items if write variable is set to True.

```
from queue import Queue

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
q = Queue()
write = False

for i in f:
    i = i.strip() # to remove newline at the end
    if i == '$':
        if write:
            # empty the queue and also print the items
            while not q.empty():
                print(q.get())
        else:
            # empty the queue
            while not q.empty():
                q.get()
        write = False
    elif i == 'string': # search string is found
        write = True
    q.put(i)

print('$')
```